# vbscript search string in multiple files

Tags: vbscript, wsh

Please advice how changes the current single incoming log file to search multiple files.

```
   Dim strTextToFind, strInputFile, strOutputFile, boolMatchCaseSensitive
   Dim objFSO, objInputFile, strFoundText, strLine, objOutputFile 


     strTextToFind = Inputbox("Enter the text you would like to search for.")
    strInputFile = "C:\Users\mmmanima\Desktop\mani\Day_16.txt"
```

iF YOU CAN NOTICED, IM ONLY ACCESS THE day_16 FILE

```
strOutputFile = "C:\Users\mmmanima\Desktop\texting As\result.txt"
   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
   Const intForReading = 1
   Const intForWriting = 2
   Const intForAppending = 8
   Set objInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strInputFile, intForReading, False)

Do until objInputFile.atEndOfStream
    strLine = objInputFile.ReadLine
    If InStr(strLine,strTextToFind) > 0 Then 
        strFoundText = strLine 
     If strFoundText <> "" Then
            Set objOutputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strOutputFile,intForAppending, True)
                objOutputFile.WriteLine strFoundText
                objOutputFile.Close
                Set objOutputFile = Nothing
         End If
End If 


     loop
  objInputFile.Close
 Set objInputFile = Nothing

 WScript.Quit
```

VBScript required to search userinput string into the share folder and there is 60  files.

Answer (score 1):

As I believe you want to search through the all files in a particular folder. Then I suggest you to loop you action while all files are read 
to do that it's easier to maintain sub or function

pseudo:

```
var inputFolder = ".\myfolder"
foreach file in the inputFolder
{
    inputFile = file
    searchIn(inputFile)
}

sub searchIn(inputFile)
{
    'do your current works here
}
```

code:

This part will give you the all file names

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
inputFldr = Replace(wscript.scriptfullname,wscript.scriptname,".\")
Set fldr = fso.getFolder(inputFldr)

For Each file In fldr.Files
 'call to your function
Next
```

----------plese aware of typos------

```
Dim strTextToFind, strInputFile, strOutputFile, boolMatchCaseSensitive
Dim objFSO, objInputFile, strFoundText, strLine, objOutputFile 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
inputFldr = Replace(wscript.scriptfullname,wscript.scriptname,".\")
Set fldr = objFSO.getFolder(inputFldr)

strTextToFind = Inputbox("Enter the text you would like to search for.")

For Each file In fldr.Files
    yourFunctionName(file )
Next

sub yourFunctionName(inputFile)
    strInputFile = inputFile    
    strOutputFile = ".\result.txt"
    Const intForReading = 1
    Const intForWriting = 2
    Const intForAppending = 8
    Set objInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strInputFile, intForReading, False)

    Do until objInputFile.atEndOfStream
        strLine = objInputFile.ReadLine
        If InStr(strLine,strTextToFind) > 0 Then 
            strFoundText = strLine 
            If strFoundText <> "" Then
                Set objOutputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strOutputFile,intForAppending, True)
                objOutputFile.WriteLine strFoundText
                objOutputFile.Close
                Set objOutputFile = Nothing
            End If
        End If 
    loop
    objInputFile.Close
    Set objInputFile = Nothing
end sub
WScript.echo "done"
WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this vbscript, i added a function **BrowseForFolder()**

```
Option Explicit
Dim strTextToFind,inputFldr,strInputFile,strOutputFile,path,fldr
Dim objFSO, objInputFile,strFoundText,strLine,objOutputFile,file,ws 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
path = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName)
strOutputFile = path & "\result.txt"

If objFSO.FileExists(strOutputFile) Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile(strOutputFile)
End if

inputFldr = BrowseForFolder()
Set fldr = objFSO.getFolder(inputFldr)
strTextToFind = Inputbox("Enter the text you would like to search for it !","Enter the text you would like to search for it !","wscript")

For Each file In fldr.Files
    Call Search(file,strTextToFind)
Next
ws.run strOutputFile
'***************************************************************************************************************
Sub Search(inputFile,strTextToFind)
    strInputFile = inputFile
    Const intForReading = 1
    Const intForWriting = 2
    Const intForAppending = 8
    Set objInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strInputFile,intForReading, False)
    Do until objInputFile.atEndOfStream
        strLine = objInputFile.ReadLine
        If InStr(strLine,strTextToFind) > 0 Then 
            strFoundText = strLine 
            If strFoundText <> "" Then
                Set objOutputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strOutputFile,intForAppending, True)
                objOutputFile.WriteLine "The Path of file ===> "& DblQuote(strInputFile) & VbCRLF &_
                "String found "& DblQuote(strTextToFind) & " ===> "& DblQuote(strFoundText) & VbCRLF & String(100,"*")
                objOutputFile.Close
                Set objOutputFile = Nothing
            End If
        End If 
    loop
    objInputFile.Close
    Set objInputFile = Nothing
End sub
'***************************************************************************************************************
Function BrowseForFolder()
    Dim ws,objFolder,Copyright
    Set ws = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = ws.BrowseForFolder(0,"Choose the folder to search on it ",1,"c:\Programs")
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        Wscript.Quit
    End If
    BrowseForFolder = objFolder.self.path
end Function
'****************************************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*****************************************************
```

Comment: Dear Hackoo, Thank you so much for your assistance.  Above vbscript working fine. However i have queries to ask. 1. is that possible to seach in two different folder? 2. currently if the strTextToFind couldn't find there is windows error pop-up, can we change this to without windows error and start back strTextToFind?

Answer (score -1):

A bit late in the day after such a long time gap to address Mara Raj's problem with Hackoo's script but here it is for any others who may be interested. On starting the script it automatically deletes any existing result.txt file. Should the script subsequently go on to find "no match"  it fails to generate a results.txt file as it would normally do if there were a match. The simplest way to correct this is to  insert:

```
If objFSO.FileExists(strOutputFile) Then
else
wscript.echo "No Matches Found"
wscript.Quit
end if
```

between "next" and "ws.run strOutputFile"